# polars native way to convert unix timestamp to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm working with some data frames that contain Unix epochs in ms, and **would like to display the entire timestamp series as a date.** Unfortunately, the docs did not help me find a polars native way to do this, and I'm reaching out here. **Solutions on how to do this in Python and also in Rust** would brighten my mind and day.

With pandas, for example, such things were possible:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd_df.timestamp, unit="ms")
# or to convert the whole col
pd_df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(pd_df.timestamp, unit="ms")
```

I could loop over the whole thing and do something like I'm doing here for a single entry in each row.

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(pl_df["timestamp"][0] / 1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

If I were to do this in Rust, I would then use something like chrono to convert the ts to a date. But I don't think looping over each row is a good solution.

For now, as the best way I have found to help me is to convert `pd_df = pl_df.to_pandas()` and do it in pandas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adapting the answer of @jqurious. Polars has a dedicated `from_epoch` function for this:

```py
(pl.DataFrame({"timestamp": [1397392146866, 1671225446800]})
   .with_columns(
       pl.from_epoch("timestamp", time_unit="ms")
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────────────┐
│ timestamp               │
│ ---                     │
│ datetime[ms]            │
╞═════════════════════════╡
│ 2014-04-13 12:29:06.866 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-12-16 21:17:26.800 │
└─────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: this is outdated for the current version of polars (0.18.4), "with_column" is now `with_columns`, "unit" is now `time_unit`